# How to do 404 link testing through selenium rc for complete website?

Tags: selenium-rc, link-checking, xenu

How can i verify a complete website's link(mostly links that are redirecting to 404 page) by using **Selenium RC**. Previously I tried to do this thong by using xenu and web link validator but in there results most of the links are showing `500 internal serevr error`. And for the pages they are showing `500 internal server error` actually don't exists in the web site.

So what is the concept if we can crawl through the website using **Selenium RC**.?

Comment: I made selenium rc use the capturenetworktraffic("xml"); and then parsed it for statusCode and URL to check against returned by the HTML response. Then made a switch to handle those statusCodes. Hope it helps point you to the right direction.